# Holographic Entanglement Entropy for a mathematician

Tags: entropy, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for this site, but figured I'd give it a shot.  I'm a mathematician (with an extremely limited background in physics) and have come across some ideas that seem related to the concept of holographic entanglement entropy as introduced by Ryu-Takanayagi.  However, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the physics literature and so am relying on this paper by [Alexakis and Mazzeo](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2250) which I understand better (specifically the last paragraph of page 4).

Unfortunately, I am having some trouble reconciling some things:

1. The Ryu-Takanayagi paper deals with Lorentz signature AdS, while the Alexakis-Mazzeo paper deals with Riemannian signature $\mathbb{H}^3$.  My results (at least at present) have to do with the later, so wonder if this is a special case of the what Ryu-Takanayagi consider or is it more of an analogy?
2. Alexakis-Mazzeo seem to define the entropy as the renormalized area, while (my understanding) is that Ryu-Takanayagi consider the full asymptotic expansion as a sort of formal entropy (and the renormalized area is is the topological entanglement entropy).  Am I missing something?  If it is the later, it seems that the Ryu-Takanayagi entropy depends on the choice of boundary defining function...is this correct?

In addition, are there any good references or surveys (or articles) on the subject that might be accessible to someone like me?  For instance, I found this paper by [Fischetti and Wiseman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04373) to be written in a language I could (more or less) understand.

**Edit:** It was suggested I add more specifics about my background.  I'm a geometer so I'm coming at this from the perspective of minimal surface theory and related areas.

Comment: you might add what area of math you're coming from? there are a number of mathematical issues in even defining entanglement for QFTs, and there have been some papers making progress on this. but it sounds like you're more interested in the geometric aspects of RT?

Comment: @4xion Good point.  I add a comment that I'm coming at this from a geometry POV.

Comment: I don't recall any broad surveys on RT or holographic entanglement entropy from a geometer's pov. But three papers that come to mind that might be of interest, which explore different geometric/topological aspects of RT (primarily in AdS$_3$) are [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7561), [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05515), and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00354). Unfortunately, these are also written for a HEP audience